# How to Print an Array into .csv without opening the file?

Tags: excel, vba, csv

Subject question is posed with respect to the reverse direction of many a related thread. Surely there must a be a simple function or answered thread I have overlooked?

Successfully extracting input files by reading contents as a single string stream into designated variable/s; then clean up by parsing for commas and quotations, and assigning each element to an array position, which is then transposed into a worksheet. However, the requirement is to populate an output file with the array's contents *without opening the target*.

Have tried countless usages of `Print #1`, `Write #1`, `GetObject`, resetting print area/zones, and still no luck. Notably: `Print` statement allows for `vbCRLf` but not shifting right or left to other columns, resulting in a printed rows on a single column.

**Code as follows**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    'A
        Dim h                   As Integer:           h = 0
        Dim i                   As Integer:           i = 0
        Dim j                   As Integer:           j = 0
        Dim k                   As Integer:           k = 0
        Dim wsf                 As WorksheetFunction: Set wsf = Application.WorksheetFunction
        Dim wb                  As Workbook:          Set wb = ThisWorkbook
        Dim ws                  As Worksheet:         Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
        Dim FileArray()         As Variant, _
            SplitDataAgain()    As Variant, _
            SplitData()         As String, _
            CopiedData          As String, _
            CleanStr            As String, _
            fPath1              As String, _
            fPath2              As String
            fPath2 = "[OUTPUT FILE]"
            fPath1 = "[INPUT FILE]"
        
        Dim Test                As Variant
            
    'B
        Open fPath1 For Binary Access Read As #1
        CopiedData = Space(LOF(1))
        Get #1, , CopiedData
        Close #1

    'C
        SplitData() = Split(CopiedData, vbCrLf)
        Do
            '1
            CleanStr = StrCleaning(i, SplitData())                  'Handle dollar values
            '2
            ReDim Preserve SplitDataAgain(i)                        'New row
            SplitDataAgain(i) = Split(SplitData(i), ",")            'Populate row
            k = UBound(SplitDataAgain(0))                           'Cols
            h = UBound(SplitDataAgain())                            'Rows
            i = i + 1
        Loop Until i > (UBound(SplitData()) - 1)
        ReDim FileArray(k, h)                                       'Proportions of file
        
        '3
        For i = 0 To h                                              'Cols
            For j = 0 To k                                          'Rows
                FileArray(j, i) = SplitDataAgain(i)(j)              'Invert and populate
            Next j
        Next i
        
    'D
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(h + 1, k + 1)) = wsf.Transpose(FileArray())
    
    'E
        Open fPath2 For Output As #1
            For i = 0 To h
                For j = 0 To k
                    Test = FileArray(j, i)
                    If j <> k Then
                        Print #1, Test,
                        Else:   Print #1, Test
                    End If
                Next j
            Next i
        Close #1
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub

Private Function StrCleaning(i As Integer, SplitData() As String) As String

    Dim rx1                  As RegExp:           Set rx1 = New RegExp
    Dim rx2                  As RegExp:           Set rx2 = New RegExp
    Dim FindStr1             As String:           FindStr1 = "((?:^|,)""[^"",]*),"          'Commas for rx1
    Dim FindStr2             As String:           FindStr2 = "(?:[""]*)([.]*)(?:[""]*)"     'Quotations for rx2
    Dim ReplaceStr           As String:           ReplaceStr = "$1"                         'Grouping of rx1 and rx2
    Dim p                    As Integer
    With rx1
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = FindStr1                                                 'Pattern of number commas
    End With
    With rx2
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = FindStr2                                                 'Pattern of quotations
    End With
    
    For p = 1 To 3
        SplitData(i) = rx1.Replace(SplitData(i), ReplaceStr)                'Removing commas
    Next p
    SplitData(i) = rx2.Replace(SplitData(i), ReplaceStr)                    'Removing quotations
    StrCleaning = SplitData(i)                                              'Return clean string
    
End Function
```

Comment: Guess you mean 'without opening the target in excel' . CSV is essentially formatted text, columns are wherever you put the separator? Add some commas? Can you provide examples of the bad output?

Comment: Hi @NickSlash. Found the answer after researching FileSystemObjects which aligned very closely with your advice and have posted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Open fPath2 For Output As #1
        For i = 0 To h
            For j = 0 To k
                Element = FileArray(j, i)
                If j <> k Then
                    Print #1, Element & ",";
                    Else:   Print #1, Element
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
    Close #1
```